# page controller with tab control

Tags: tabs, uipagecontrol

I'm using a tabbed application. I want to have a page control in one of my tab views.  When I place the page control and link it to another view controller, I can change pages like I want too, but the tab bar disappears completely from the bottom.  How can I keep my tab bar to stay even in a different page control view?

Comment: To clarify I am using iOS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're doing this in storyboard:

Option-drag from the tab view controller to the target view controller.

A pop up will appear - make sure you pick the 'View Controllers' option under 'Relationship Segue' rather than anything under 'Manual Segue'.